# Jq - extract last element (no array)

Tags: json, jq

How to extract the last element - "date"?

Expected output = "2019_10_29_12_01_01"

```
$ cat snapshots.json | jq '.snapshots[] | select (.state == "SUCCESS") | {date: .snapshot}'
{
  "date": "2019_10_21_12_01_01"
}
{
  "date": "2019_10_28_00_01_01"
}
{
  "date": "2019_10_29_12_01_01"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `last`, e.g:

```
last(.snapshots[] | select(.state == "SUCCESS"))
| .snapshot
```